# Infinite scrolling with mouse

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, scrolling

I know we're able to scroll a background image hardcoded or using awsd keys(or arrows) if they're pressed. But what about scrolling it with mouse movement? So I have a piece of panoramic image as a background and I wanna embody background transform depending on mouse pos or rel. I came up with mouse.get_rel() pygame function

ultra simplified code snippet:

```
from pygame import *

screen = display.set_mode((1920, 1080), RESIZABLE)

gx = -12288
gy = -5120

background = image.load(f'Content/Map/Overcast/Overcast_HQ.jpg')

run = True
while run:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            run = False
        elif e.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            rel = mouse.get_rel()
            gx += rel[0]
            gy += rel[1]
    screen.blit(background, (gx,gy))
    display.flip()
```

but the thing i don't like here is if i move the cursor out of pygame window or if i reach a screen edge no more movement is detected while i'm actually moving a mouse. I need something similar to "mouse locking" when the cursor pos doesn't change (cursor itself dissapears) and player is able to rotate a camera limitlessly as far as his table allows to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
def lock_mouse(gx, gy, virtual_surface, check_pos_offset = False):   #enables limitless move with mouse
    px = virtual_surface.get_width()//2
    py = virtual_surface.get_height()//2
    mouse_pos = (px, py)
    rel = mouse.get_rel()
    gx += rel[0]
    gy += rel[1]
    if mouse.get_pos()[0] < mouse_pos[0] - 100 \
            or mouse.get_pos()[0] > mouse_pos[0] + 100 \
            or mouse.get_pos()[1] < mouse_pos[1] - 100 \
            or mouse.get_pos()[1] > mouse_pos[1] + 100:     # if set mouse pos to 0 every frame then mouse move will be flicky, that's why magic numbers are used
        mouse.set_pos([px, py])
        if check_pos_offset:    #if snapping to locked mouse mode then we have to compensate mouse position offset
            gx -= rel[0]
            gy -= rel[1]
    return gx, gy
```

So I had checked up this method right before I asked a question. The reason it hadn't worked is I was checking mouse position offset every frame and after each frame I reset mouse coordinates. There was a kind of movement but it was very flicky. And then I thought so what if we don't reset coords every frame but when the difference between default and current coords would be more than something; a range of 100 was enough for this.

And the last thing is we need to switch between locked mouse mode and a free mouse. And when the mouse is free its position might be far away from its allowable zone of 200 pixels. So once mouse is moved after going locked mode it drags to the default position and the background image also gets swiped because mouse movement in that frame is taken by `mouse.get_rel()`. In order to compensate it we can immediately substract the exact amount of movement off `gx` and `gy`.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the following to lock the mouse into the screen based on size that way they can't click out of it.

import pyautogui
import time

## Set the coordinates of the window you want to lock the mouse to

window_x = 100
window_y = 100
window_width = 800
window_height = 600

## Set the interval for updating the mouse position (in seconds)

update_interval = 0.1

try:
while True:
# Get the current mouse position
current_x, current_y = pyautogui.position()

```
    # Ensure the mouse stays within the window bounds
    new_x = max(window_x, min(current_x, window_x + window_width))
    new_y = max(window_y, min(current_y, window_y + window_height))

    # Move the mouse to the new position
    pyautogui.moveTo(new_x, new_y, duration=0.1)

    # Pause for the specified interval
    time.sleep(update_interval)
```

except KeyboardInterrupt:
pass  # Handle Ctrl+C to exit the loop